# Where can I find colored indicators for use in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, colors, status

I need color indicators. Need to be able to do green, yellow and red. Anybody know how? I looked through the available icons/etc in Interface Builder but did not see anything like them.

Like this:
[green indicator http://allynbauer.com/permafrost/green_indicator.png](http://allynbauer.com/permafrost/green_indicator.png)

Comment: Rich, you are no fun. :)

Comment: @Allyn: Bling is not a valid tag and adds nothing to the question.

Comment: See what I mean? No fun!

Comment: @Allyn: The internet is serious business. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpreMR7p5ik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the images used in iChat/Mail/etc inside the InstantMessage.framework. The directory is `/System/Library/Frameworks/InstantMessage.framework/Resources`

You can get `status-available.png`, `status-away.png`, and `status-idle.png`

Of course, rather than needlessly including extra image files in your app, you could also include the InstantMessage.framework in your app and use `[IMService imageNameForStatus:]` to get the names of the system images for each status. See the [IMService Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/InstantMessageFrameworkRef/Classes/IMService_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/IMService/imageNameForStatus:)

Answer (score 1):

Using 10.6.8 and could not find the icons in the `InstantMessage` framework resource folder.

So alternatively got those from `/Applications/uTorrent.app/Contents/Resources`

(if you have uTorrent of course)

Answer (score 1):

Using 10.8, I found them in `/System/Library/Frameworks/IMCore.framework/Resources` which is a symbolic link to `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Resources`

This post is quite old but I had some difficulties to find theses icons, so... :)